# better way to "clean" Bearer token

Tags: c#, http-headers, authorization, httprequest, dotnet-httpclient

I'm adding an auth header token from my current request so I can hit another API, but when I add the `AuthenticationHeaderValue` scheme (which cannot be blank), it duplicates "Bearer" in the token... so I just called Replace() on it to get it working...

```
var rawToken = this.HttpContext.Request.Headers["Authorization"];
var cleanedToken = rawToken.ToString().Replace("Bearer ", "", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
requestMessage.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", cleanedToken);
HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.SendAsync(requestMessage).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

But this call to Replace() feels like a dirty hack. Is there a battle-tested library method to handle this instead?

Comment: Maybe use AuthenticationHeaderValue.Parse static method?

Comment: @Evk - this worked great, thanks. I'd be happy to accept as an answer

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using `AuthenticationHeaderValue.Parse(rawToken)` should do the job, as it will automatically extract "Bearer" scheme (or any other scheme) and token from the raw value, removing the need to pass it explicitly.